# Python Pandas Plotting Two BARH side by side

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a plot that is similar like this,
[image]

The left hand side chart (the plot with legend) is derived from `df_2`, and the right hand side chart is derived from `df_1`.

However, I cannot make the two plots side-by-side share the y-axis.

Here is my current way to plot:

```
df_1[target_cols].plot(kind='barh', x='LABEL', stacked=True, legend=False)
df_2[target_cols].plot(kind='barh', x='LABEL', stacked=True).invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

The code will resulted two plots in two different "canvas".

1. How can I make them side-by-side sharing the y-axis?
2. How can I remove the label in y-axis for the left hand side chart (chart derived from `df_2`)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create shared subplots using `plt.subplots(sharey=True)`. Then plot the dataframes to the two subplots.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.randint(5,15, size=10)
b = np.random.randint(5,15, size=10)

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":a})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"b":b})

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)

ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.yaxis.tick_right()

df["a"].plot(kind='barh', x='LABEL',  legend=False, ax=ax)
df2["b"].plot(kind='barh', x='LABEL',ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first was using

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
axes[0], axes[1]
```

but then couldn't place the y-ticks on the right side (so they appear centered), for some reason would not work. Now using 'ax' and 'ax2' and `ax.yaxis.tick_right()` works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).